# How to merge nested attributes in strong params with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

In my controller of a rails 6 app I have the following strong parameter:

`params.require(:item).permit(:summary, tasks_attributes: [:id, :name])`

I want to merge the following into the tasks attributes:

```
user_account_id: user_account.id
account_id: current_account.id
```

I've tried the following with no success:

```
params.require(:item).permit(:summary, tasks_attributes: [:id, :name])
.reverse_merge(tasks_attributes: [user_account_id: user_account.id, account_id: current_account.id]
```

If I try

```
.reverse_merge(account_id: current_account.id)
```

It successfully merges into the item, but no such luck trying to get it into the tasks attributes. Other posts mentioned the reverse_merge but assuming they work in a has_one/belong to relationship.

If not possible in the strong params, I would have to do something like the following after pulling in the params:

```
@item.tasks.each { |task| task.user_account_id = user_account.id }
```

Comment: Or you can go `params[:item][:task_attributes].merge(user_account_id: user_account.id, account_id: current_account.id)`

Comment: `I've tried the following with no success` -- what's message do you have? It should work: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-reverse_merge

Comment: No error message, it just didn't set the values. The issue seems to do with the "0", "1", etc. before each nested attribute, I can manually set 1 at a time by doing the following, `.reverse_merge(tasks_attributes: [ '0': [user_account_id: user_account.id]])` so would need to loop through, was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the nested attributes and merge each attributes hash:

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item)
        .permit(:summary, tasks_attributes: [:id, :name])
        .tap do |wl|
          wl.tasks_attributes.each do |hash|
            hash.reverse_merge!(
              user_account_id: user_account.id, 
              account_id: current_account.id
            )
          end
        end
end
```

AFAIK ActionController::Parameters does not really have a built in utility for doing what you want and its really outside the scope of what strong parameters is designed for which is to whitelist parameters for mass assignment.